# How can I figure out which tableView Cell is selected when collectionview is scrolled horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tableview, collectionview

I have collectionView inside TableViewCell.
TableView has 1 section and 4 rows.

I want to figure out which row of tableviewcell is selected when collectionView is Scrolled Horizontally.

I tryed to figure out by putting tableView row in "var nowRow" variable like below code. But It does not work.

How can I find out which row of tableviewcell is selected?

```
class Home2ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,  UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var posts = [Post]()
    var nowRow = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // get posts elements here 
        //posts.append(element).......
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return posts.count // 4counts 

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       // let cell = DetailMutiTableViewCell()
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailMutiTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailMutiTableViewCell

        nowRow = indexPath.row

        cell.post = posts[nowRow]
        cell.collectionView1.delegate = self
        cell.collectionView1.dataSource = self

        cell.collectionView1.reloadData()
        return cell
    }



    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts[nowRow].imageUrls.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MultiImagesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MultiImagesCollectionViewCell

        let photoUrlString = posts[nowRow].imageUrls[indexPath.item] // ←error occured
            let photoUrl = URL(string: photoUrlString)
            cell.imageView1.sd_setImage(with: photoUrl)


        return cell
    }
}
```

editeditedit

Comment: store it manually in your viewcontroller

Comment: What about the `indexPathForSelectedRow` property of `UITableView` ? Or implementing the selection methods of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol ?

Comment: @McNight, interacting with a `collectionView` does not select the tableView cell the contains it, so `indexPathForSelectedRow` is `nil` and `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` is not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have no doubt discovered, interacting with the collectionViews in your table rows does not trigger the tableView method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`, and `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` is `nil` because no row has been selected.  You need a way to map from the `collectionView` to the `indexPath.row` that contains it.  This information is known at `tableViewCell` setup time.

Add a dictionary to your `Home2ViewController` that maps a `UICollectionView` to a row `Int`:

```
var collectionViewRow = [UICollectionView : Int]()
```

Add the entries in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` where you know the `row` and `collectionView`:

```
collectionViewRow[cell.collectionView1] = indexPath.row
```

Then, anytime you have a `collectionView`, you can look up its row:

```
let row = collectionViewRow[collectionView]!
```

Here's the whole code:

```
class Home2ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,  UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var posts = [Post]()
    var collectionViewRow = [UICollectionView : Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // get posts elements here
        //posts.append(element).......
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return posts.count // 4counts
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // let cell = DetailMutiTableViewCell()
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailMutiTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailMutiTableViewCell

        collectionViewRow[cell.collectionView1] = indexPath.row

        cell.post = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.collectionView1.delegate = self
        cell.collectionView1.dataSource = self

        cell.collectionView1.reloadData()
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let row = collectionViewRow[collectionView]!
        return posts[row].imageUrls.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MultiImagesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MultiImagesCollectionViewCell

        let row = collectionViewRow[collectionView]!
        let photoUrlString = posts[row].imageUrls[indexPath.item] // ←error occured
        let photoUrl = URL(string: photoUrlString)
        cell.imageView1.sd_setImage(with: photoUrl)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. The force unwrap of the dictionary lookup won't fail because the `collectionView` will be in there.  If you want to unwrap it with `if let`, you'll need to decide what to do when you don't get a row (which shouldn't happen).
2. This method could fail if your table allows editing (user can rearrange order of rows or delete rows).  If you don't support editing, then this will work fine.  To support editing, you could change the dictionary to `[UICollectionView : UITableViewCell]`.  Then, given a `UICollectionView`, you could look up its `cell`, and then call `let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)` to get the `indexPath` and your row is then just `indexPath.row`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Down voter, what is your reason for the down vote? I can't address your issues/concerns without some feedback.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook accidentally. Im looking for how to upvote your question. I will definetly fix it.

Comment: I made two new accounts and vote up your answer twice. I hope it works. I am new to stackOverflow. when I look for how to mark best answer, I mistook to click down vote.   Im sorry, I apologize to you.

Comment: @kou, I appreciate the sentiment, but you are not the down voter. You do not have enough reputation to up vote or down vote. Someone else down voted. Please don’t use more than one account on Stack Overflow. That is forbidden.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you.